# ajax call to login.php , response failed

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery

I am doing login.php with the ajax call..Below is my ajax bit code and login.php code..while giving valid user name and password also..am getting invalid user name or password message..am totally failed understand these lines of code

```
$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
    if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax) // in login.php, Many thanks

$("#login").click(function() {    
    var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        is_ajax: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: login.php,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response == 'success')
                $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                });
            else
                $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");    
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

and this is the login.php code.

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']) && $_REQUEST['is_ajax']) {
    $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];

    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];
    $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
    $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);

    $user_name = "root";
    $pass_word = "root";
    $database = "test";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
    $uname = quote_smart($uname, $db_handle);
    $pword = quote_smart($pword, $db_handle);
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 =  $uname AND L2 = md5($pword)";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        echo "success"; 
    }

    mysql_close($db_handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Why is the `url` parameter not a quoted string?  Right now it is the `php` property of an object named `login`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Sir..i have put the ('login.php')codes even though am not getting success message..

Comment: Someone before me suggested testing a fixed (known good) strings for `$uname` and `$pword` in the PHP file instead of pulling from `$_POST`.  Do you get a success message if you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your PHP is not very save and works with GET/POST because you are using `$_REQUEST`. 
Debug `login.php` first, if you are getting any PHP Notices you have to fix those because it will change your ajax response.

try running this in browser `yoursite.com/login.php?is_ajax=1&username=XXXX&password=XXXX`

If you are getting only "success" word in the browser, then see what JavaScript is receiving by adding `console.debug(response)` to the `success` handler. Preview the value in firebug console or chrome console.

Comment: Sir am getting nothing in the browser "yoursite.com/login.php?is_ajax=1&username=XXXX&password=XXXX" by giving valid values...

Comment: I just noticed that you get some stuff from POST, for test purposes change it to `$_REQUEST` and if still does not work, then debug your php code. Set your SQL Select to a variable and dump to ensure it looks right, etc...

Comment: Sir am getting 'failure message'

Comment: Sir am using this query " $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 ='$uname' AND L2 ='$pword'");" but error is "query is empty"

Comment: set query to variable and preview. `$sql = "select ..."` + `echo $sql`. You'll see whats going on, then preview the data in database...

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You need to sanitize your user input before using it in a query. `htmlspecialchars` doesn't do it. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` (maybe `quote_smart` does this?).
2. Your URL is not quoted, so it is interpreted as code. Put `login.php` in quotes.
3. Make sure you understand what `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` are. It looks like you don't actually use `$username` or `$password` anywhere, so it doesn't look like this is hurting you right now, but you should know that the entire contents of the `$_POST` array are also found in the `$_REQUEST` array (along with `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`).
4. For debugging, in your PHP script, you should echo some kind of failure message to see where the script fails and in your jQuery script, you should add the response to your failure message to see what the response actually was.

Try this:

```
$("#login").click(function() {    
    var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        is_ajax: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response == 'success')
                $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                });
            else
                $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password. (debugging, response = '". response ."'</p>");    
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

login.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['is_ajax']) && $_POST['is_ajax'])
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "root";
    $database = "test";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 = '{$username}' AND L2 = MD5('{$password}')");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 0)
        echo "success";
    else
        echo "username '{$username}' and password '{$password}' not found";

    mysql_close($db_handle);
}
else
    echo "is_ajax = {$_POST["is_ajax"]}";
```